# jQuery - UI Dialog - looking for a smart solution for a timed close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I wrote the following:

```
// Called with setTimeout(magicDialogDelayedClose, 2500);
function magicDialogDelayedClose() {
    $(".ui-dialog").fadeOut(function() {
        dialog_general.dialog('close');
    }); 
}
```

The above is called with setTimeout when I show a notice dialog that I want to auto close in 2.5 secs.

The problem I'm noticing with this is that if the use Manually closes a dialog this timer still is running. If the user then opens a new dialog (which is very possible) the timer can then close that NEW dialog.

What's a smart way to handle this?j

Comment: can you show us your *notice dialog* code? the calling and where the above code resides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear a timeout (stop it from firing) by storing it in a variable and then using the `clearTimeout()` method:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(magicDialogDelayedClose, 200);
clearTimeout(timeout);
```

So if someone manually closes your dialog then stop the timeout from  carrying on there and then.

**A safe way to clear the timeout** would be to determine whether `timeout` is not null before doing so:

```
function safeClearTimeout(timeout) {
    if (timeout != null)
        clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

Comment: I like that idea a lot. Problem is that if timeout isn't set you get a Uncaught ReferenceError: dialog_timeout is not defined

Comment: @AnApprentice Then check to see if it is null before clearing it?

Comment: true, I just set a global var timeout. that did the trick. so a nice solution. thanks! I can't accept for another 7 mins ( i hate that about stackoverflow.

Comment: @AnApprentice: For future reference, you can avoid the not defined error by either defining it at the beginning of your code or explicitly look within the `window` namespace via `window.dialog_timeout`. Nevertheless, having global timeouts like this may be suboptimal depending on your ultimate wishes. See my solution for a method that implements a closure within the insertion function. Marcus' solution, while effective, will make it so that dialog A, inserted at +0s will no close until +3s if dialog B is inserted at +1s, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @AnApprentice: `magicDialogDelayedClose` in this sense as a "global" function is a misnomer, but what it means is that when and only when `magic...` is called, ALL items that match its selector will be closed (by your implementation). Specific dialogs will not be closed independently of others. If your delay is 2s, and it gets reset in an interval shorter than that (e.g., every 1.5 seconds, a new dialog box is displayed), none of the increasing number of dialog boxes will ever close. There is a place and time for both Marcus' and my solution, but it's helpful to be able to know the difference.

Answer (score 4):

Coarsely speaking, in your situation, you don't want to have a function that applies globally. You want to queue a close on each dialog as it appears. As of version 1.4, jQuery has implemented the [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function that accomplishes just this. It adds a null action to the animation queue, so that subsequent chained animation functions come after the delay in the queue.

It would be implemented as follows:

```
function insertDialog() {
  // substitute your insertion code here
  var d = $('<div class="ui-dialog"></div>').appendTo($('#dialog_area'));

  // add a 2.5s delay into the animation queue, then add
  // a fadeOut with $(this).close() as a callback
  d.delay(2500).fadeOut(function(){ $(this).close() });
}
```

Comment: +1. Elegant solution. Very good. I think the jQuery UI event options for dialog have changed since this was posted. Now you want to call:

`d.delay(2500).fadeOut(function() { $(this).dialog('close') });`

Answer (score 1):

Another twist, busy so only tried it in FireFox, but it worked ...

```
$('#dialogBox').html("Put some text message here.").dialog("open").delay(2500).fadeOut(function(){ $(this).dialog("close") });
```